# analyze frames while recording video on Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image

I'm fairly new to Android programming. I encountered a problem, for which I didn't find a solution until now. I want to record a video with the camera of the Android phone and while recording this video an saving it I would like to analyze the single frames of the video. Here I only want to do calculations on the images, I don't want to manipulate the images and write them into the video.

The first thing I found relating to video recording on Android was the MediaRecorder, but it seems that there is no option to get the images of the video stream.

It would be nice if someone had a hint for me on how to approach this problem.

Regards,

Nawabu

Comment: seems a work for ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with Android 4+:

If you're confortable with OpenGL ES, you could implement http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener.html and obtain the SurfaceTexture object.

From this object, the texture ID associated with the SurfaceTexture will be updated to the latest preview frame from the camera. You can also read back the RGB texture data to the CPU for further processing using glReadPixels().